# SSRS Report called from ReportViewer control displays no data in the report when called with a parameter

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, parameter-passing

Can you look at my coding and let me know what I'm missing or doing wrong?

I have a SSRS report that is called from a ReportViewer control and the ProcessingMode for this control is Remote. The report also has 1 parameter in it's DataSet.

In the code I placed a MsgBox to make sure the code is finding the parameter and returning the parameter name. I am trying to stick the value of 10 into the parameter for playerID 10. Data for this player does exist.

I believe I need to add some more code to make this work but I'm not sure what else to add.

When the code executes the report is displayed but no data is shown in the report.

Here is the coding:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim paramList As Generic.List(Of ReportParameter) = New Generic.List(Of ReportParameter)()

    With Me.ReportViewer1
        .ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Remote

        With .ServerReport
            Dim pinfo As ReportParameterInfoCollection = .GetParameters()

            For Each p As ReportParameterInfo In pinfo
                MsgBox(p.Name)
                paramList.Add(New ReportParameter(p.Name, 10))
            Next

            If paramList.Count > 0 Then
                .SetParameters(paramList)
            End If
        End With

        .ShowParameterPrompts = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution though it took a while to find it.

These lines of code will get it working:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim rpParameters = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportParameter

    rpParameters.Name = "PlayerID"
    rpParameters.Values.Add(10)

    Me.ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = False
    Me.ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rpParameters)
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```